# How to save geolocation data that persist within Firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, geolocation, firebase

I want to save geo coordinates upon submit of input for internal data sorting.

It shows the coordinates, i.e. loading the current location. However, the **data is not saved** but rather **continually refreshed**. I tried to save it as:

> position:{lat:'',lng:''}

How to ensure the data is saved and not just a refresh of current location?

**Navbar controller**

```
 app.controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, $location, Post, Auth, $state, Geolocation) {
      $scope.post = {
        title:     '',
        lat:  '',  
        lng:  ''
      };
```

**Submit function under same controller**

```
 $scope.submitPost = function () {
    Post.create($scope.post).then(function (ref) {
    $location.path('tab/posts/' + ref.name()); 

      $scope.post = {
        title:     '',
        lat:  '',  
        lng:  ''
      };

      $scope.position = null;
      $scope.message = 'Determining location...';  

      new Geolocation().then(function (position) {
        $scope.position = position;
      }, function (reason) {
        $scope.message = 'Could not be determined';
      });
```

**Also under the main controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Post) {

  $scope.posts = Post.all;
  $scope.post = {
    title:      '',
    lat:  '',       //inserted geodata to be reflected in main page
    lng:  ''
  };
```

Comment: I don't see any use of Firebase in the code you include. Given the number of technologies you're using, it might be better if you set up a reproduction of the problem in a fiddle/bin/plunkr.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the reply! Will set it up and post here shortly. Sorry about that.

Comment: If you cannot reproduce the problem, maybe you can try to simplify the plunkr until you can reproduce the problem? Given the title of your question, there must be a way to reproduce it with fewer files and technologies involved. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: See my answer. You might be able to get a better answer if you write up a proper question that involves fewer technologies. Something like "why is my controller getting invoked multiple times?", should be able to reproduce the behavior without using Firebase and Ionic. By reducing the number of technologies used, you broaden the audience that can answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scope is getting recreated all the time. By the time your `submitPost` method runs, the position is gone from the current `$scope` again. This is fairly easy to determine by putting some `console.log` statements in there.

```
console.log('clearing position');
$scope.position = null;
$scope.message = 'Determining geolocation';

new Geolocation().then(function (position) {
  console.log('setting position');
  $scope.position = position;
}, function (reason) {
  $scope.message = 'Could not be determined';
});
```

You will see that it logs:

> clearing position
>
> setting position

When you initially load the page. And then another:

> clearing position

When you click the "New post" link. So it seems that your controller gets re-executed there, which clears the position from the scope.

The quickest fix I could find was to simply set the geolocation on the `$rootScope` and use it from there:

```
//console.log('clearing position');
//if (!$scope.position) $scope.position = null;
$scope.message = 'Determining geolocation';

new Geolocation().then(function (position) {
  console.log('setting position');
  $rootScope.position = position;
}, function (reason) {
  $scope.message = 'Could not be determined';
});

////////////////////////////  NEW POST  ////////////////////////////
$scope.submitPost = function () {
  Post.create($scope.post).then(function (ref) { //postId works
    $location.path('tab/posts/' + ref.name());   // replace with postId
    console.log('submitPost: position=');console.log($scope.position);
    $scope.post = {
      title:      '',
      timestamp:  new Date().toUTCString(),
      position:  $rootScope.position
    };
  });
};
```

This way the position is still in the root scope by the time we reach `submitPost`.

As you get better using tools like `console.log` and the Chrome Angular devtools, you can probably figure out why the controller is executed a second time (clearing the position from the current scope). But this should get you on your way.

Comment: Im still trying to find out why. Initially my guess was because the main post page is attached to PostCtrl via the stateprovider while the nav submit button (also on the main page) has another NavCtrl. Somehow removing the geocode from NavCtrl to insert to PostCtrl doesnt solve the problem though.

Comment: A user's location is a global property, so I think that putting the geolocation in $rootScope makes sense here.

Comment: Got it, thanks Frank. One last question. Do I have to change position from `position: ''` to `position:  $rootScope.position` for all 3 instances of the $scope.post ={} codes? I think the one at PostCtrl seems unnecessary though...

Comment: Just a side question, would it be better to isolate and save only lat/lon data and query, or query on the entire "position" data? If the former, would it be saving it as separate longitude:$rootScope.longitude and similar for lat?